# How to post a picture or link in an event via the Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

```
$params = array(
'access_token' => $this->facebook->getAccessToken(),
'message' => 'My message',
'picture' => 'http://bookshop.fbsocialapps.com/images/homepage-illustration.jpg',
);

$post_id = $this->facebook->api('/'.$result['id'].'/feed','post',$params);
//$result['id'] is the id of the event
```

when I do that, only the message is published.
If I replace the $result['id'] by "me" it publishes correctly. I have the exact same problem when publishing a link.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It's a FB bug, although your code is a little off, you need to post to $result[id']/photos.

Subscribe to help get it fixed
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/225316074217855?browse=search_4f2f7576c5bc32d87041759